# Charactaristic polynomial, algebric multiplicity and diagonaizability

Tags: linear-algebra

1.If i know that the akgebric multicity of each eigenvalue of a real matrix $A$, $n \times n$ is 1, can i conclude that the number of eigenvalues equals to $n$.

2. In order to A to be diagonaizable, the number of eigenvalues i need should equal the rank of A or n, if A is nxn?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, yes, you can. The characteristic polynomial is degree $n$, so it has $n$ (complex) roots when counted with multiplicity. If the multiplicities are all $1$, then those $n$ roots must be distinct.

For question 2, consider the zero matrix. It is trivially diagonalizable, but has rank $0$ and it has exactly one eigenvalue. Or the identity matrix, which has rank $n$ and exactly one eigenvalue.

For diagonalizability, you need that the *algebraic multiplicity* of $0$ as an eigenvalue must be equal to the *nullity* of the matrix. And there is a corresponding requirement for every other eigenvalue as well (the nullity of $A - \lambda I$ must be equal to the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$). The actual number of eigenvalues is not really important at all for this consideration (although, if there are $n$ of them, then you know both the algebraic multiplicities and the nullities are all $1$), and neither is the rank (the rank-nullity theorem means you *can* use the rank if you want to, but it is the nullity that is the important quantity).

Comment: Thanks but the degree of the charactaristic polynomial is not $n$ for $A, n \times n$? so if the rank of different matrices is different yet we can conclude that the charactaristic polynomial will be of degree $n$ regardeless the rank of the matrix, isnt it?

Comment: @Alon The characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix will _always_ have degree $n$. Regardless of what other properties it may have. Even for the zero matrix, which has rank $0$ and characteristic polynomial $x^n$.